What is this Sci fi film set in the future?
So this film is set in the future where it's now just a community of people but still with a government type structure. 
I don't remember loads but here's what I do remember:

The people take an injection shot every day and do their day to day stuff.  
They don't really see colour and everything is very simple. 
There are these cameras that fly around so there is never no privacy.
There's a man who is like a type of "keeper of memories" of the community who hold all the memories of what earth used to be like, the good/bad/ugly.
A boy is chosen to be the next one like him. 
The man transfers his memories to the boy over time. 
These two will be the only people who have the memories but then the boy and one of his other friends stop taking the shot.

Please help me out its driving me mad!

You're looking for The Giver, based on the Lois Lowry book of the same title.

Following a calamity referred to as The Ruin, society is reorganized into a series of communities, and all memories of the past are held by one person, the Receiver of Memory. Since the Receiver of Memory is the only individual in the community who has the memories from before, he must advise the Chief Elder, and the other Elders, on the decisions for the community.

Here's the trailer:




Perfect thanks so so much!
